# Ember JS tutorial: TypeError: Cannot read property 'maps' of undefined

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-testing

I am currently running through the official EmberJS tutorial on their website and I'm on [this part](https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.13.0/tutorial/service/). Everything works perfectly in the app itself when I run `ember serve` but the problem is when I run the unit tests for the new service. I am running `ember test --server` and I get an error that I took a screenshot of below:

[image]

The unit test code:

```
import { moduleFor, test } from 'ember-qunit';
import Ember from 'ember';

const DUMMY_ELEMENT = {};

let MapUtilStub = Ember.Object.extend({
  createMap(element, location) {
    this.assert.ok(element, 'createMap called with element');
    this.assert.ok(location, 'createMap called with location');
    return DUMMY_ELEMENT;
  }
});

moduleFor('service:maps', 'Unit | Service | maps', {
  needs: ['util:google-maps']
});

test('should create a new map if one isnt cached for location', function (assert) {
  assert.expect(4);
  let stubMapUtil = MapUtilStub.create({ assert });
  let mapService = this.subject({ mapUtil: stubMapUtil });
  let element = mapService.getMapElement('San Francisco');
  assert.ok(element, 'element exists');
  assert.equal(element.className, 'map', 'element has class name of map');
});

test('should use existing map if one is cached for location', function (assert) {
  assert.expect(1);
  let stubCachedMaps = Ember.Object.create({
    sanFrancisco: DUMMY_ELEMENT
  });
  let mapService = this.subject({ cachedMaps: stubCachedMaps });
  let element = mapService.getMapElement('San Francisco');
  assert.equal(element, DUMMY_ELEMENT, 'element fetched from cache');
});
```

From the tutorial, my understanding is that `this.subject({ cachedMaps: stubCachedMaps })` will set up all the `maps` for me but it seems the service itself might be undefined, leading to no property `maps`. Is this right? What could be causing this?

System specs from running `ember --version`:

- ember-cli: 2.13.0
- node: 6.8.1
- os: darwin x64

Comment: yes, much like. I thought I was insane so I started copy pasting their code. This is broken. I'll wait to see if anyone answers here

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So ran into the same thing. Looks like between each test the previous stub got wiped. so I added it again in the second test and it worked great:

```
test('should use existing map if one is cached for location', 
  function(assert) {
    assert.expect(1);
    let stubCachedMaps = Ember.Object.create({
      sanFrancisco: DUMMY_ELEMENT
    });
    let stubMapUtil = MapUtilStub.create({ assert });
    let mapService = this.subject({ mapUtil: stubMapUtil, cachedMaps: stubCachedMaps });
    let element = mapService.getMapElement('San Francisco');
    assert.equal(element, DUMMY_ELEMENT, 'element fetched from cache');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The test code you posted should work, so the problem must be elsewhere.

Can you compare the rest of the code to the completed version of the tutorial app? You can clone the repo @ https://github.com/ember-learn/super-rentals

All the tests run fine, including the maps service.

Comment: I did a diff but not sure what to make of the results. Here's the link to the diff.txt I made: https://github.com/Sticksword/ember-super-rentals-tutorial/blob/master/diff.txt

Alternatively can just clone my repo and then do `git diff` on the official ember repo as a separate `remote`.

Answer (score 1):

I run at the same thing, too. The solution by @cythrawll works, but it's not the root cause of `TypeError: Cannot read property 'maps' of undefined` error.

In tutorial they forget to add

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.22"></script>
```

in `test/index.html` file. [Issue](https://github.com/emberjs/guides/issues/1931) is already reported.

Comment: Still the utility class should be mocked like @cythrawll did